# Android: Setting up a form in XML

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-linearlayout

I'm having a little bit of trouble getting a form set up using a LinearLayout associated with an activity class. All of my EditText and TextViews are grouped together in one line at the top of the screen. How do I put a line break between each of these items?

Here is the XML for my activity class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_detail"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/detailEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dateLabel"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/timeLabel"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="top|right"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/PrioritySelect"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/priority"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:entries="@array/prioritylist">
    </Spinner>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your layout android:orientation="horizontal" to android:orientation="vertical", It will work.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to my mind is - set the orientation as vertical for the LinearLayout. If you still want a divider of sorts with the current layout, you can use a button with 1dp width like this between each view-

```
<Button
    android:background="#000"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a default style for showing a line break between each items in LinearLayout. (API 11+)

Something like below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    style="?android:buttonBarStyle">
  <TextView style="?android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
    ... />
  <TextView style="?android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
    ... />
  <TextView style="?android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
    ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

or custom way:

drawable/vertical_divider.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

  <size
    android:width="1dp"
    android:height="@dimen/your_custom_height" />

  <solid android:color="@color/your_custom_color" />

</shape>
```

layouts/activity_xxx.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:divider="@drawable/vertical_divider"
      or use the system one below
    android:divider="?android:attr/listDivider"
    android:dividerPadding="8dp"
    android:showDividers="middle">
  <TextView ... />
  <TextView ... />
  <TextView ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

or you can do this in code:

```
mLinearLayout.setDividerDrawable(customDividerDrawable);
mLinearLayout.setDividerPadding(customPadding);
mLinearLayout.setShowDividers(LinearLayout.SHOW_DIVIDER_MIDDLE);
```